# Where is the view article in joomla?

Tags: joomla2.5

This may be a very stupid question, but where is view article in Joomla after you create it?
It happens that I'm stuck with a project in Joomla 2.5. I'm coming from Wordpress.

I created an article and I can't put it in any category of the site because it will show, the client will not like that. It is in Uncategorised category.

How do I see that article? How can I get to it? What is the link ? I know the alias, the category, the id, etc. How I make the link from this ones?

I'm very frustrated. I tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a menu link (single article) to the article.

Comment: Yep, that was it! I didn't get it the first time, but you point me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad to help! I didn't answer in detail 'cause i was through my mobile.